# Apache reverse proxy with LDAP authentication for multiple Application

Tags: apache, proxy, ldap, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

We have to perform Apache as a reverse proxy with LDAP Authentication (AWS EMR)for 2 different applications. Reverse Proxy and LDAP are working Fine but the Contents of Application's Web Page are not loading fully. We are getting 404 error code for some of the dependencies of the webpage through reverse proxying .

Here is our httpd.conf file:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 ProxyHTMLExtended On
 RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass /zeppelin/ http://localhost:8890/
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:8890 /zeppelin
  ProxyPass /jupyter/ http://localhost:8900/
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:8900 /jupyter


<Location /zeppelin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap::url"
    AuthLDAPBindDN  "bindn"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "bindpassword"
    Require valid-user
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /zeppelin/
    RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</Location>
<Location /jupyter/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap::url"
    AuthLDAPBindDN  "bindn"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "bindpassword"
    Require valid-user
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /jupyter/
    RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</Location>
 DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory /var/www>
   Options -Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am running into the same problem deploying jupyterhub behind LDAP and an APACHE Reverse Proxy.  I am able to access the jupyter hub through the reverse proxy and login through LDAP, but I am unable to fully start the server.

Comment: ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location /jupyter>

    ProxyPass "http://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter"
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"
  </Location>

  <LocationMatch "/jupyter/(user/[^/]*)/(api/kernels/[^/]+/channels|terminals/websocket)(.*)">
    ProxyPassMatch ws://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter/$1/$2$3
    ProxyPassReverse ws://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter/$1/$2$3
  </LocationMatch>